# compare two hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to compare 2 hashes in ruby where one of the hash contains the numeric values in quoted string, which makes that a string. Consider the following 2 hashes:

```
hash1 = {"A"=>"0", "B"=>"1", "SVHTID"=>"VH", "D"=>"0", "E"=>"19930730", "F"=>"TEST - DEPOSIT", "G"=>"2.25000000"}

hash2  = {"a"=>"0", "b"=>1, "c"=>"VH", "d"=>0,"e"=>19930730, "f"=>"TEST - DEPOSIT", "g"=>2.25}
```

Now the code i have written so far is as follows:

```
hash2 = Hash[hash2.map {|key, value| [key.upcase, value] }]

hash1.each{|k,v| hash1[k] = hash1[k].to_i if hash1[k].match(/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)}

hash1.keys.select { |key| hash1[key] != hash2[key] }.each { |key| 

puts "expected #{key} => #{hash1[key]}, but found #{key} => #{hash2[key]}"

     }
```

what is does is that it also converts the float value to integer and the original value is lost.

What i want is that when the above 2 hashes are compared the output should contain only G as mismatched type and following should be printed:

```
Expected: G=>2.25000000 but found G=>2.25
```

Comment: What should be the result when a hash contains the same character as both lowercase and uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# normalization
h1, h2 = [hash1, hash2].map do |h|
  h.map do |k, v|
    [k.to_s.downcase, v.to_s.to_i.to_s == v.to_s ? v.to_i : v]
  end.to_h
end
```

Now we are ready to compare:

```
h1.reject { |k, v| h2[k].nil? || h2[k] == v }
#⇒ { "g" => "2.25000000" }
```

This might be printed, formatted etc as you want.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, what if in future i want to round off the value of g and also match the same, means 2.25000000 is rounded off to 2.25 and matches with the value of hash2[g]

Comment: Then in future you’ll ask another question here on SO, or adopt the answer given above for dealing with floats as well as with integers.

Comment: No, this is no rude by any means. This is how SO works and if you were giving a minute to read rules before asking questions, you’d know that.